# Mapinfo SQL ClientxStore Minimum Distance

Tags: sql, mapinfo

I have two tables in mapinfo:

```
Client ( Id, X, Y, storeId)
Store (StoreId, StoreName, X, Y)
```

I need to get closest `Store` (minimum distance between client and store) to every client and store it into `Client` table,
I can't use excel, spss or anything else than mapinfo.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Closest distance between a Store and a Client is challenging already but very doable. But closest Store for many Clients is difficulty squared and requires a lot of imagination. Have you tried anything by the way?

Comment: Yes, I've tried creating a intermediate table that has all client with calculated distance related to any store but when you do this you lost IdStore and you'll never know what store is the closest

Comment: try to show your work then. I guess you made a query also?

Comment: For this kind of operations you can use Oracle Spatial if you have already an oracle database for storing map informations. Once I have worked with MapInfo in .Net and we had used oracle spatial for geometric operations of data stored on database. Of course there should be some kind of Mapbasic queries also for realizing this operation if you store the data in mapinfo tables.